# Repeated elements' onclick event only works for first row

Tags: javascript, php, html

Below you will find my code I am using to pull the data from the table along with the image I want to repeat with each table row listed in the last button tag Class=plusbtn

```
{

        $event .= '     <div  style="border-bottom:1px solid gray;padding:2px;width:100%;float:left;"><div id="eventslist" onclick="goevent('.$row['id'].');">
                        <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
                            <h4 style="margin:0;"><span id="eventuser" style="width:50%;float:left;text-align:left;font-size:14px;"><img src="https:///login/profile/'.$row['profile_img1'].'" style="width:35px;height:37px;border-radius:20px;margin-left:-4%;background:url(http:///img/person-placeholder.jpg) no-repeat center" class="img-rounded"> <b>'.$row['user'].'</b></span><span style="float:right;text-align:right;font-size:12px;margin-top:9px;margin-right:-25px;">Posted: '.$row['stdate'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br/><br/><b><span style="font-size:20px;float:left;">'.$row['fname'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></b></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div style="width:109%;float:left;">
                            <img src="http:///login/image/'.$row['name'].'" style="width:100%;height:35%;border-radius:10px;margin-left:-4%;background:url(https:///img/load.gif) no-repeat white" class="img-rounded">
                        </div>
                        <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
                            <p style="margin-bottom:0;">'.substr($row['description'],0,110).'...</p>
                        </div>
                </div><div><button class="plusbtn" onclick="plusrate(\''.$likecount.'\');"><a onclick="document.getElementById(`myImage`).src=`https:///img/fav4.png`"><img id="myImage" src="https:///img/fav3.png" style="opacity: 0.7;height:25px;max-width:100px"></a></button><span id="likeqnty" class="likeqnty">0</span> <b>Likes</b></div></div>   ';
    }
```

using this set up the button image appears for every entry but I can only click the button at the first entry on my page. When I type echo around the button (echo"button") appears on the page

How can I make the button repeat with every table entry and work correctly switching from fav4 to fav3.

Answer (score 0):

You problem stands in the fact that IDs should be unique. But all your images have the same ID.

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById(`myImage`).src=`https:///img/fav4.png`">
    <img id="myImage" src="https:///img/fav3.png" style="opacity:0.7;height:25px;max-width:100px">
</a>
```

Clicking on any of those links will always change the FIRST image with id `myImage`.

You'd like to change your onclick javascript to target the image respectively to the current click target.

```
<a onclick="this.getElementsByTagName(`img`)[0].src=`https:///img/fav4.png`">
    <img id="myImage" src="https:///img/fav3.png" style="opacity:0.7;height:25px;max-width:100px">
</a>
```

In this code, we use this as it is the current DOM element that received the click. And retrieve the image inside it, and change its src value. This makes sure that the targeted image is relative to where the user clicked.

Comment: The IDs are the same due to the img/fav4 switching to img/fav3 when clicked. It is a like button the first image is an open heart and the second image when clicked is a filled-in heart

Comment: I think you are mixing up ID and SRC... SRC is the picture SouRCe, while ID is just an IDentifier for the html element.